# I can't change the Visibility of an "embedded" View in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a View (.xaml) which inside I have another view "embedded":

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=My_ViewModel}" Visibility="{Binding Path=My_Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Views:My_View/>
    </Grid>
```

I have a Button that changes the My_Visibility value.

```
    protected void ExecHideMyView()
    {
        My_Visibility = false;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("My_Visibility");
    }
```

But it doesn't change the Visibility at all. I tried the following:

- Changing all the pertinent properties to `public`
- Checking to see if my main ViewModel was really set as the context of the main View, and yes it was.
- Debugging to see if the `ExecHideMyView()` was really called, and yes it was.
- Putting the `Visibility=...` as attribute of `<Views:My_View/>`.

Now I'm out of ideas... appreciate any suggestion.

**Edit:** I removed the `DataContext="{Binding Path=My_ViewModel}"` and it suddenly worked. It seems the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I set the `DataContext="{Binding Path=My_ViewModel}"` it searched for the `My_Visibility` inside of the `My_ViewModel` instead of the main ViewModel.

So the solution was to move the `My_Visibility` to inside `My_ViewModel`.